# Is there a shortcut for activating Low Power Mode in iOS 9?

Tags: iphone, battery, ios

I don't use my iPhone with a mobile data plan and I don't care if the polling frequency for background apps gets lowered a bit.

Is there an easier/faster way to activate the **Low Power Mode** than using **Settings** -> **Battery** -> **Low Power Mode**?

Is the **Do Not Disturb** mode that I can set using the quick settings, pulled up from the bottom of the screen, equivalent or is this a different thing? I saw some comparisons of **Low Power Mode** with **Do Not Disturb** mode in descriptions of the new feature.

**Note:** Using Siri is not an option for me due to privacy concerns.

Comment: This is a enhancement request I submitted to Apple. I was like - I'd like that  feature ALL THE TIME. No word if it's implemented yet...

Comment: @bmike: thanks, I'm hoping for this to turn up in one of the next updates then. Seems I'm not alone with a desire for this shortcut.

Comment: @bmike: a shortcut was introduced to re-enable it. See my answer below. But it may have only been introduced with iOS 10, I don't know when exactly it appeared. Just found it by accident.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** this was added starting [in iOS 11 (Apple Video)](https://youtu.be/o7xfp5__ZOQ).

In brief:

1. Open Settings
2. Select Control Center
3. Tap Customize Controls
4. Find Low Power Mode option and tap the green +

[more info](https://www.payetteforward.com/how-to-add-low-power-mode-to-control-center-on-iphone-fix/)

---

**Original:**
I was very surprised to open Control Center on iOS 9 and **not** see a battery icon! Apple manages to fill other things in very nicely and that would have been very logical (from my view).

Unfortunately, as of iOS 9.0, there is no simplified way to toggle Low Power Mode. As you discovered the only way to enable it is to open the Settings.app and then opening Batteries. If you'd find it faster, you can now search the Settings app by pulling down past the "top" of the list in the app.

In addition, when your phone hits 20% battery, it will alert you and offer to enable the feature.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know a way to suggest features or report issues? Perhaps this could make it into the next minor update.

Comment: That would be great! There doesn't seem to be an iOS 9 - specific feedback form, but there's one for iPhone: http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html

Comment: awesome. Just sent this as a request regarding *Workflow/Efficiency*. Thought it's more fitting than a mere *Enhancement Request*.

Comment: You can submit bug reports and feature/enhancement requests at https://bugreport.apple.com/ as well. They may or may not respond. They will have at least seen it though most likely even if they don't respond to your ticket. Often times it will be marked as duplicate. That's fine because the more people that request something the more likely it is that they'll address it.

Comment: I was surprised to not see a button to activate this mode in control center as well.

Comment: Yes, and NightShift got one which is something I (and perhaps I'm alone) would likely use less as I'm just leaving it automatic.

Comment: My guess is, btw, that Apple decided that since low power mode restricts phone home features of apps (lowers background updating frequency), they may not make the same profits if everyone enables low power mode?!

Answer (score 7):

Two Options:

**Option 1:**
Ask Siri to "enable low-power mode". This requires an Internet connection of some type because of Siri so if you are, in fact, using an iPhone without a data plan then you will need to be on wifi.

**Option 2:**
On iPhones featuring force-touch, you can force-touch the settings icon on the homescreen, navigate directly to battery and toggle low power mode there. Not much of a shortcut but it is something.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a jailbroken device, you can activate it in Control Center via this: http://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/10/19/how-to-toggle-low-power-mode-via-control-center/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a third party app such as iLauncher and create a custom button as a shortcut to call a custom scheme URL that will open the battery settings and option to turn on/off low power mode

Battery (updated for iOS 9):

prefs:root=BATTERY_USAGE

http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/ios-8-widget-customisations-using-launcher.1782093/

Answer (score 0):

In **iOS 10**, it turns out, you have the option on the lock screen to re-enable the low power mode from the notification you get when the battery is sufficiently charged.

I made two screenshots to illustrate:

[image: Battery sufficiently charged]

Now when you pull this notification to the left (as you would do to dismiss/clear it), the following will be visible:

[image: Enable low power mode again]

So there you have it, a shortcut has been introduced, although I can't tell when exactly. And that shortcut of course only may have appeared in iOS 10, leaving several generations of devices behind.

NB: I removed as much of the lock screen background from the screenshots; i.e. they're touched up a bit around the notification message.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can turn of most of the individual items affected by the low power mode in settings, such as mail fetch, background app refresh and automatic downloads. I'm not sure but this should have the same effect as the low power switch.

Answer (score -1):

Siri can turn off "Low Power Mode"

"Hey Siri, turn [on/off] Low Power Mode"

Comment: The OP specifically requested a solution which does not involve Siri: "**Note**: Using Siri is not an option for me due to privacy concerns."